# What the difference between 'make me' 'get me' 'has me' in meaning 'to force'

Tags: word-usage

In many cases 'make me' 'get me' 'has me' doing something mean 'to force'. What is the difference between them in this meaning? Is there any sense to use one or the other?

Comment: Even my question duplicates another one I think new answers complement this complex area with a lot of nuances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**get me**" implies that they overcame some resistance.

> I finally **got** my friend to watch Star Wars after bugging her for
>   years about it.

means she didn't want to watch it for a long time, and I finally succeeded in convincing her to watch it.

"**has me**" implies some sort of authority, but not necessarily force.

> When I got to the restaurant, I **had** the valet park my car for me.

mean I was able to "order" the valet to do it because I had money. We use this most commonly with transactions, although it can be used with other types of authority, e.g.,

> The policeman had me pull over to a side road to get away from the
>   traffic.

"**make me**" implies more force or authority than "has me"

> I didn't want to clean my room, but my mom **made** me.

means my mom overcame my hesitation using her authority/force as the head of the household.

Comment: +1 for the distinctions.  Sometimes speakers use **get** informally to mean **have**. An executive in a company might say  *I'll get HR to send you the necessary forms.*  The exec's not expecting any resistance from HR and really means that he or she will tell HR to send the forms, have HR send them. Perhaps there's some implication that he or she may have to ask HR nicely or convince them of the need?